# Having an issue using substring in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor and having issues with basic javascript. I want to get the text from an element and only take the the first 5 characters.

When I try to run this statement

```
    var searchDate = element(by.id("tag")).getText().substring(0,5);
```

I get this  error

Message:
     TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'substring'

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `Object [object Object]` is a promise.

Do instead:

```
element(by.id("tag")).getText().then(function(text) {
  var searchDate = text.substring(0,5);
});
```

Comment: thanks that worked. Coming from using Selenium with the Java the idea of promise is new to me . I will have to some reading up on it.